# c# Event log Full or Not

Tags: c#

How to now whether the Application Eventlog is full or Not.there is any option to clear all the events in application event log. My code is

```
 EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
            log.Source = "Voting Editor Tool";
            log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
```

Comment: are you getting an error while trying to write to the event log? Are you trying to write from a windows application or a web application? You will need to make sure that whichever user is running the application (web or windows) needs to have permission to write to the specific event log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try catch

```
try
{
    EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
    log.Source = "Voting Editor Tool";
    log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
}
catch (Win32Exception w32ex)
{
    // full
}
```

To clear the event log use

```
log.clear();
```

Quote from the docs.

> Event logs are set with a maximum size that determines how many entries they can contain. When an event log is full, it stops recording new event information or begins to overwrite earlier entries. If event recording stops, you can use this method to clear the log of existing entries and allow it to start recording events again. You must have administrator permissions to the computer on which the log resides to clear event log entries.

Comment: It would probably be better to catch the more specific Win32Exception rather than Exception.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to the event viewer and specify the log is circular so old entries will be eaten by new ones as needed.

I am sure you could specify this when you run your installation script which creates the new event log for your application.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this situation we need to set the “OverflowAction” Action Property to either “OverwriteAsNeeded” or “OverwriteOlder”
as shown below:

```
enter code here

EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();                    
eventLog.Source = "ViewImagePDF";
if (eventLog.OverflowAction != OverflowAction.OverwriteAsNeeded)
{
    eventLog.ModifyOverflowPolicy(OverflowAction.OverwriteAsNeeded, 1);
}
eventLog.WriteEntry("This is sample information", EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

Please follow the  [LINK](http://siddikhadarvalipothuganti.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/how-to-write-an-event-log-to-the-event-viewer/)
Thanks,
Siddi.